# HeadUp Notification not working Background in android <=25.(in foreground working in All API Target)

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I have problem in HeadUp notification in Android Version 25 or lower in background only..working in foreground

i am using react-native-firebase library

as per Android Notification OverView https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications

in android 7.1 (API Level 25) and lower

**The notification has high priority and uses ringtones or vibrations on devices running Android 7.1 (API level 25) and lower**

so tried to setAudio and setVibrate for displayNotification but not working in background

**NOTE** - 
**Foreground HeadUp Notification** -  working in all API level 25 to 27..
**Background HeadUp Notification** -  working only in Android 8 (API level 26 and higher) not working in Android 7 (API Level 25 and lower)

created channel for API Level 26 (Android 8) and higher

```
const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel('test-channel', 'Test Channel', firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max)setDescription('My apps test channel');
// Create the channel
firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);
```

set listener for get/display notification

```
this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification) => {
console.log(notification)
  const notification = new firebase.notifications.Notification({
    sound: 'default',
  show_in_foreground: true,
})
  notification.setNotificationId(notification._notificationId)
  notification.setTitle(notification.title)
  notification.setBody(notification.body)
  notification.android.setVibrate(1000)
  notification.android.setChannelId('test-channel')
  notification.android.setSmallIcon('ic_launcher')
  notification.setSound('default')
 notification.android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.Max)

  firebase.notifications().displayNotification(notification);
});
```

for this piece of code getting HeadUp notification in foreground

want headUp notification even in older version of android (7.1 and lower)